# Getting ejabberd to notify an external module on client presence change

Tags: python, xmpp, ejabberd

I have an ejabberd server at jabber.domain.com, with an xmpp component written in python (using sleekxmpp) at presence.domain.com.

I wanted the component to get a notification each time a client changed his presence from available to unavailable and vice-versa.

The clients themselves don't have any contacts.

Currently, I have set up my clients to send their available presence stanzas to admin@presence.domain.com, and I do get their online/offline presence notifications. But I feel this isn't the right approach.

I was hoping the clients wouldn't be aware of the component at presence.domain.com, and they would just connect to jabber.domain.com and the component should somehow get notified by the server about the clients presence.

Is there a way to do that?
Is my component setup correct? or should I think about using an xmpp plugin/module/etc..

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, sleekxmpp is a synchronous/blocking library that will block the communication until it finishes current task processing, this means when the next message comes to your ejabberd and forwarded to your sleekxmpp, it will have to wait till it finishes, consequently, slowing the overall performance that you used ejabberd for .. how did you get around this?

Comment: I ditched the sleekxmpp component configuration and set up the ejabberd module that @ppolv described in his answer. Now the xmpp server sends a message to an external service whenever a client connects/ disconnects. The external service keeps track of the client's presence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not difficult to write a custom ejabberd module for this.   It will need to register to presence change hooks in ejabberd,  and on each presence packet route a notification towards your external component.

There is a pair of hooks  'set_presence_hook'  and 'unset_presence_hook' that your module can register to,  to be informed when the users starts/end a session.

If you need to track other presence statuses, there is also a hook 'c2s_update_presence' that fires on any presence packets sent by your users.

Other possibility, without using a custom module, is using shared rosters.  Add  admin@presence.domain.com  to the shared rosters of all your users,  but in this case they will see this item reflected on their roster.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try your solution. When I get to it I'll post here again.

Comment: Used your suggestion for a custom module. This is the most transparent to our users and the least amount of problems (until now ;)

Comment: @DoodyP : can we extend the discussion in this chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64981/ejabberd-with-mysql

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for a component to subscribe to a user's presence exactly the same way a user does. Also it is possible for the user to subscribe to a component's presence. You just have to follow the usual pattern, i.e. the component/user sends a `<presence/>` of type `subscribe` which the user/component can accept by sending a `<presence/>` of type `subscribed`.

You can also have the user just send a presence to the component directly.

There is no need to write custom hooks or create proxy users.

Comment: Thanks, This is what I'm doing right now, but it feels like this setup highly couples clients (users) to the server implementation.

Comment: Which of the three is "this"?

Comment: sorry, this was "user to subscribe to a component's presence".

Comment: You don't *have* to do both subscriptions if you don't need to. But if your component becomes available/unavailable, this gives you the minimum coupling necessary.